# Expand Unity Text Window Size In Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a custom string field in the inspector and I want to give it a large box.

Currently its this:

[image]

and I want it to be this:

[image]

I looked through https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.html but didn't seem to find anything that increases inspector window size.

Comment: Why not post your current Editor code?

Comment: Its just a public field at the moment `string description`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't mention what type of Input field you are using for the custom Editor and no code at-all, I will provide the possible solution. You sort it out yourself.

Simply enable `wordWrap`.

Depending on what you are using:

```
GUI.skin.textArea.wordWrap = true;
```

or

```
EditorStyles.textField.wordWrap = true;
```

You can even do this with the `TextArea` attribute.

```
 [TextArea(3,10)]
 public string text = "blah blah blah";
```

Comment: <3 exactly what I wanted